# How to use symfony la make a get request on url like http://example.com?name=john&message=hello to send sms

Tags: symfony, url, get, request

How to use symfony to make a GET request on url like http://example.com?name=john&message=hello to send SMS?

1. I have an API like  http://example.com?name=john&message=hello to a SMS provider
2. I don't know how to use in in symfony 4 to send a SMS
3. I have already populated the name and the message

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

use an http client like [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

you have to tell us more about it to see the relation to symfony but an example controller could be something like

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/sms")
 */
public function smsAction()
{
    $name = 'john';
    $msg = 'hello';
    $guzzleClient = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.com']);
    $response = $guzzleClient->get('/', [
        'query' => [
            'name' => $name,
            'message' => $msg,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send sms you have to use SMS Gateway/API like Nexmo or Twilio for example. They both have a PHP library, in most of the cases you will need to purchase a (virtual) phone number and you will receive your API keys which are necessary when using the library.

So sending an sms with symfony is not really complicated I guess.

Assuming you have a controller like:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SmsController extends AbstractController
{
    public function smsAction(Request $request, SmsService $smsService)
    {
        $fromNumber = $this->getParameter('sms_number_sender');
        $toNumber = $request->query->get('recipient');
        $message = $request->query->get('message')
        $smsService->sendMessage($fromNumber, $toNumber, $message)
    }
}
```

And a SmsService defined below:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SmsService
{
    // Can be any Sms client like TwilioClient for example
    private $smsClient;

    public function __construct(SmsClient $smsClient)
    {
        $this->smsClient = $smsClient;
    }

    public function sendSms(int $fromPhoneNumber, int $toPhoneNumber, string $messageBody)
    {
        $this->smsClient->sendMessage(
            $int $toPhoneNumber,
            [
                'from' => $fromPhoneNumber,
                'body' => $messageBody
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

If you are using recent versions of symfony, all new classes are automatically registered as Service, so just have to add the service you want to use as a parameter in your Controller action. If you want to inject a SmsClient in the constructor of your SmsService, you will need to declare it as service if it is an external library.

It just an example to give you an idea about how you could proceed in order to send sms with Symfony. It is not a working example.

[This is how TwilioClient deals with Symfony](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-sms-reminders-with-symfony-php-framework)